# Can you map a directory to another server in Apache

Tags: apache

Is it possible to map a directory to another server in Apache?

For example I want http://www.example.com/blog to map to server B and I want everything else on http://www.example.com/ to map to server A

Comment: Sure that is possible. Read about the proxy module in the official documentation.

Comment: use redirect inside apache configuration

Answer (score 1):

you can use mod_proxy on apache server and configure reverse proxy to "forward" /blog direcotry to another server. ie:

```
ProxyPass /blog http://127.0.0.1:3080/
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://127.0.0.1:3080/
```

will forward all requests to `/blog` to server running on localhost (127.0.0.1) on port 3080.